# How to use HIVE/SQL to query some values in array and count the total?

Tags: sql, hive

I have this table with many entries with one section that looks like this:

```
{"user":{
         "id": "ABC123"
         "color": "green"}}
```

Say that I want to count how many users have color "green" and color "red." How would I do that? I think I need to use `lateral view explode(user)` first but couldn't get my query to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can select the color using the dot notation. No need to explode anything.

```sql
select user.color, count(1) from table group by user.color
```